# ParcelJS: Strip the .html

Tags: javascript, url-routing, parceljs

I just started looking into **ParcelJS**.
Something I noticed immediately is the trailing `.html`s on every url.
Clicking the link created with the following `pug` code...

```
p Hello World
a( href="./something/index.pug") Some link
```

...will take me me to `localhost:1234/something/index.html`

**How do I make it so that:**
1, it will simply take me to `/something` and display `index.html`
2, manually going to `/something` does the same thing

If it's not possible with the Parcel core, what is the absolute simplest way to make it work?
Thank you!